# How to use Arrays em Dictionaries for create a object (like js) in Swift

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, swift2

I'm trying to get some iPhone data to my database on my site. But the data I need to send by create one object(like a JS) - with Arrays and Dictionaries, for json. The example of "object":

```
var data = {
    itens: {
       [id: "123", name: "Watch"], 
       [id: "321", name: "iPhone"],
       [id: "213", name: "iMac"] 
    },
    show: {
        bar: 1,
        aside: 1,
        footer:0,
        main:0
    }
}
```

I am a developer Javascript, and recently fell in love with Apple Swift.

My question is: **How do I create an "object", as in the example above, in Swift**?.

Comment: From the Apple Swift documentation (read everything, it's very good): [Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a dictionary where the key is a `String` and the value is something else, so:

```
let data : [String: Any] = [
    "items": [
        ["id": "123", "name": "Watch"],
        ["id": "321", "name": "iPhone"],
        ["id": "213", "name": "iMac"]
    ],
    "show": ["bar": 1, "aside": 1, "footer": 0, "main": 0]
]
```